# figure out total seconds based on timestamp

Tags: mysql, datetime

I have a table with three columns (user, timestamp, activity).  The activity is basically check in or check out.  How do I generate a query to view total seconds a user has clocked in by day?

There is an issue with the system that sometimes has two check ins but only one check out...in which case I want to only take the lowest check in timestamp.

I came up with something like this (activity: 1 = check in, 0 = checkout):

```
select a.user_id, a.d, time_to_sec(TIMEDIFF(b.created_at, a.created_at)) total_secs,
 a.created_at check_in, b.created_at check_out
from (select user_id, created_at, date(created_at) d, @rownum := @rownum + 1 AS num from table, (SELECT @rownum := 0) r where activity = 1 order by user_id, created_at) a
join (select user_id, created_at, date(created_at) d, @rownum2 := @rownum2 + 1 AS num from table, (SELECT @rownum2 := 0) r where activity = 0 order by user_id, created_at) b 
on a.user_id = b.user_id and a.d = b.d and a.num = b.num
```

However, I think relying on rownum is not accruate

Comment: Can you safely assume that the checkin and checkout happen within a timeframe, let's say 1 day?

Comment: If there is a checkin within a day, there should be a checkout as well (95% of the time).  Users can forget to checkout though until next day

Comment: but this issue (forgetting checkout) is not related to the other issue (two check-ins on one day)?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your requirement correctly, you want the number of seconds between a checkout and the earliest check-in before that, but after the previous checkout.

So what you would need is a query that joins a checkout with the previous checkout and then with the earliest check-in between these two activities.

`select 
  curr_co.user_id, 
  curr_co.created_at, 
  max(prev_co.created_at) 
from 
  table as curr_co
left outer join 
  table as prev_co 
    on (curr_co.user_id = prev_co.user_id and curr_co.created_at > prev_co.created_at and curr_co.activity = _checkout_ and prev_co.activity = _checkout_)

group by curr_co.user_id, curr_co.created_at`

This query should give you a list of checkouts with previous checkouts per user.

Now select all check-ins in between and from those the minimal and calculate the diff.

`select ... min(ci.created_at), time_to_sec(TIMEDIFF(min(ci.created_at), curr_co.created_at))
... join
  table as ci
    on (ci.user_id = curr_co.user_id and ci.created_at < curr_co.created_at and ci.created_at > prev_co.created_at and ci.activity = _check-in_)`